# How to set a default open view on the left pane of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When starting VS Code, the "Folders" view is usually open (by default) on the primary side bar.

After moving the "Folders" view to the bottom pane and back to the primary side bar, the primary side bar is empty when I start VS Code.

Is there a way to have the Folders view (or the last opened view) open by default when starting VS Code?

Comment: First, do this command: `View: Reset All Views` to fix the problem after moving the Explorer.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, the actual command was `View: Reset View Locations` but it worked.